# C# Questions about the binding model structure

Tags: xamarin.forms

*DataModel Class

```
public DataModel()
            {
                this.MeasureA = new BindingList<MiddleMeasure>()
                {
                    new MiddleMeasure()
                    {
                        
                    }
                };  
            }
    
    
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
```

*MiddleMeasure Class

```
public class MiddleMeasure 
    {
        public BindingList<MeasureData> MeasureB
        {
            get; set;
        } = new BindingList<MeasureData>();


        public MiddleMeasure()
        {
            MeasureB.Add(new MeasureData()
            {
                Title = "500",
                Title2 = 500,
                Data = 10,
            });

            MeasureB.Add(new MeasureData()
            {
                Title = "501",
                Title2 = 501,
                Data = 20,
            });


            MeasureB.Add(new MeasureData()
            {
                Title = "503",
                Title2 = 503,
                Data = 30,
            });

            MeasureB.Add(new MeasureData()
            {
                Title = "504",
                Title2 = 504,
                Data = 40,
            });
        } 
    }
```

- MeasureData Class

  public class MeasureData : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
  private string m_Title;
  private double m_Title2;
  private double m_Data;

  ```
            public MeasureData()
            {

            }

            public MeasureData(double title, double data)
            {
                this.Title2 = title;
                this.Title = title.ToString();
                this.Data = data;
            }


            public string Title
            {
                get => this.m_Title;
                set 
                {
                    this.m_Title = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Title));
                }
            }

            public double Title2
            {
                get => this.m_Title2;
                set
                {
                    this.m_Title2 = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Title2));
                }
            }


            public double Data
            {
                get => this.m_Data;
                set
                {
                    this.m_Data = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Data));
                }
            }



            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
  ```

It is a structure with MiddleMeasure in DataModel and MeasureData class in it.

The class to bind to the itemsource is the MeasureData class.

this.xDataGrid.ItemsSource = this.m_Model.MeasureA;
If you try this, it won't bind.

Binding like this.m_Model.MeasureA[0].MeasureB is possible, but not what I want. All MeasureB in MeasureA must be bound.

how can i solve it?

Comment: You appear to have a 3d set of data - how do you plan to map that onto a 2d grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you misunderstand the binding value in your code.

> this.xDataGrid.ItemsSource = this.m_Model.MeasureA; If you try this, it won't bind.

`this.xDataGrid.ItemsSource = this.m_Model.MeasureA`: this line set the itemsource as the `BindingList<MiddleMeasure>()` which just have one item(MiddleMeasure) in it.  Just like the `this.xDataGrid.ItemsSource = BindingList<MiddleMeasure>(){ new MiddleMeasure() }`. So the ItemSource just have one item. And there is only a `BindingList<MeasureData>` property on the only item.

> Binding like this.m_Model.MeasureA[0].MeasureB is possible, but not what I want. All MeasureB in MeasureA must be bound

The value of the `this.m_Model.MeasureA[0].MeasureB` is `BindingList<MeasureData>`. So you bind successfully when you set it as the itemsource.

> The class to bind to the itemsource is the MeasureData class

The the value of the `this.xDataGrid.ItemsSource` must be `BindingList<MeasureData>`. But you said all MeasureB in MeasureA must be bound. **So you need to declare a variable( type of `BindingList<MeasureData>` ) to get MeasureA's every item's MeasureB.**

If so, the `MiddleMeasure` class has no meanings.You can just let the MeasureA be type of `BindingList<MeasureData>`.

Comment: There are a few things I haven't added.
The DataModel class has other properties.

The MiddleMeasure class also has other properties. Therefore, it cannot be regarded as a BindingList<MeasureData> type.

Comment: But you said **the class to bind to the itemsource is the MeasureData class.**. So each item is a MeasureData class. @하하파파

Comment: Or you can use a `BindingList<MeasureData>` to get the MeasureA's all the MiddleMeasure's MeasureData. @하하파파